# How to change delivery address on checkout - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm customizing a magento store and I have the following problem.

Imagine that a customer of the store has 4 different delivery addresses, addresses already registered in the system.

Due to the customization I am making, I offer the customer who is buying in the store the option to choose which address he wants to deliver through a `<select>`, on a page outside the magento.

I have the deed code in the database, that is, the `entity_id` number for the address I want to change in the request that is in progress, according to the client's selection.

And that's exactly where my problem lies:

I need to tell the magento the address code I want to use at the checkout to finalize the order.

Magento by default, throws the client's default address in the ShippingAddress

Example of what I need: `$checkout->setShippingAddress(entity_id)`, however, I can not make it work.

using the command below, I can get all the data from the checkout open:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData();
```

I need to change the delivery address to a new address, which is already registered in the system.

Can someone help me?

I do not know what to do anymore.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
if ($customerAddress->getId()) {
    $address->importCustomerAddress($customerAddress)->setSaveInAddressBook(0);
}
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```